# Solving implicit function and passing in three arguments

Tags: python, scipy

[image]

In the equation above I want to solve for f and pass in Re, D, and epsilon. Here is my code below:

```
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

# Colebrook Turbulent Friction Factor Correlation
def colebrook(Re, D, eps):
    return fsolve(-(1 / math.sqrt(f)) - 2 * math.log10(((eps / D) / 3.7) + (2.51 / Re * math.sqrt(f))), f)
```

Would I use fsolve() or solve()? I read up on fsolve() on Python's main site, however I don't understand some of the inputs it wants. Thank you in advance!

Also, I am using Spyder (Python 3.6)

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia page on "Darcy friction factor formulae"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_friction_factor_formulae) has a section on the [Colebrook equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_friction_factor_formulae#Colebrook%E2%80%93White_equation), and shows how f can be expressed in terms of the other parameters using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

[SciPy has an implementation of the Lambert W function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.lambertw.html), so you can use that to compute f without using a numerical solver:

```
import math
from scipy.special import lambertw


def colebrook(Re, D, eps):
    """
    Solve the Colebrook equation for f, given Re, D and eps.

    See
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_friction_factor_formulae#Colebrook%E2%80%93White_equation
    for more information.
    """
    a = 2.51 / Re
    b = eps / (3.7*D)
    p = 1/math.sqrt(10)
    lnp = math.log(p)
    x = -lambertw(-lnp/a * math.pow(p, -b/a))/lnp - b/a
    if x.imag != 0:
        raise ValueError('x is complex')
    f = 1/x.real**2
    return f
```

For example,

```
In [84]: colebrook(125000, 0.315, 0.00015)
Out[84]: 0.019664137795383934
```

For comparison, the calculator at https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/colebrook-equation-d_1031.html gives 0.0197.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information regarding SciPy. It was very helpful.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what this line of code is doing? x = -lambertw(-lnp/a * math.pow(p, -b/a))/lnp - b/a