# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero (Solving colebrook (nonlinear) equation with Newton Raphson method in python)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, physics, newtons-method

I have tried solving the colebrook (nonlinear) equation for frictional factor in python but I keep getting this error:

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/BDG/Desktop/kkk/www/Plots/jjj/Code.py", line 49, in <module>
    f = Newton(f0,re)
  File "c:/Users/BDG/Desktop/kkk/www/Plots/jjj/Code.py", line 20, in Newton
    eps_new = func(f, Re)/dydf(f, Re)
  File "c:/Users/BDG/Desktop/kkk/www/Plots/jjj/Code.py", line 13, in func
    return -0.86*np.log((e_D/3.7)+((2.51/Re))*f**(-0.5))-f**(-0.5)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

I am trying to find the friction factor (f) for this [equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-0.86*log%28%282.51%2F%28Re*sqrt%28f%29%29%29%2B%28%28e%2FD%29%2F%283.7%29%29%29%3D1%2Fsqrt%28f%29):

`-0.86 * log(2.51 / (Re * sqrt(f)) + e / D / 3.7) = 1 / sqrt(f)`

at varying values of Reynold's number (Re) and plotting f against Re.

This is the code below, please help.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import time


#Parameters
e_D = 1e-4

eps=1e-7

def func(f, Re):
    return -0.86*np.log((e_D/3.7)+((2.51/Re))*f**(-0.5))-f**(-0.5)

def dydf(f, Re):
    return (1.0793/(Re*((251*f**-0.5)/(100*Re)+(10*e_D)/37)*(f**1.5)))+(1/(2*(f**1.5)))

def Newton(f0, Re, conv_hist=True):
    f = f0
    eps_new = func(f, Re)/dydf(f, Re)
    iteration_counter = 0
    history = []

    while abs(eps_new) >= eps and iteration_counter <= 100:
        eps_new = func(f, Re)/dydf(f, Re)
        f = f - eps_new
        iteration_counter += 1
        history.append([iteration_counter, f, func(f,Re), eps_new])

        if abs(dydf(f, Re)) <= eps:
            print('derivative near zero!, dydf =', dydf(f,re))
            print(dydf(f,re), 'iter# =', iteration_counter, 'eps =', eps_new)
            break
        if iteration_counter == 99:
            print('maximum iterations reached!')
            print(f, 'iter# = ', iteration_counter)
            break 

    if conv_hist:
            hist_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(history, columns=['Iteration #', 'Re','f', 'eps'])
            hist_dataframe.style.hide_index()

    return f
startTime = time.time()

Re = np.linspace(10**4,10**7,100)
f0 = 0.001
for re in range(len(Re)):
    f = Newton(f0,re)
endTime = time.time()

print('Total process took %f seconds!' % (endTime - startTime))
plt.loglog(Re, f,  marker='o')
plt.title('f vs Re')
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor')
plt.grid(b=True, which='major')
plt.xlabel('Re')
plt.ylabel('f')
plt.savefig('fvsRe.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post the whole traceback of your error? Somewhere you are trying to divide by zero.

Comment: `for re in range(len(Re))` is incorrect, `re` should go through each value in `Re`, it should not be an index

Comment: Just as a sidenote, plotting f vs Re won't work. `f` is a float and `Re` is an array

Comment: FYI: You can compute `f` without using Newton's method.  See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126008/solving-implicit-function-and-passing-in-three-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
return -0.86*np.log((e_D/3.7)+((2.51/Re))*f**(-0.5))-f**(-0.5)
```

When `Re` is 0 this fails. This happens because of:

```
for re in range(len(Re)):
    f = Newton(f0,re)
```

I think what you wish to do instead is:

```
for re in Re:
    f = Newton(f0,re)
```

However, this won't work because you wish to plot `f` vs `Re`. So instead you should make f a list and append the results:

```
f = []
for re in Re:
    f.append(Newton(f0,re))
```

[image: Final result]

Comment: Thank you guys so much! You are lifesavers!